# Angularjs :- how to get funtion's response using $http.get()?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, yii2, angular-http

## I am new in anggular js. I have a test.html page.

## test.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14  /angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
   <!--  <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td> -->
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("../../../frontend/controllers/CategoryController/Index")
.success(function (response) {
        //$scope.names = response.records;
        console.log(response);
    });
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
==================
category controller
==================
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

 /**
 * Site controller
 */
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
      * @inheritdoc
       */
    public  $str;
    public function actionIndex(){
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $id = 2015;

        return $id;
       }
     }
    ?>
```

When i run test.html then the request(call) will go to the cust.php page and return response.
Please suggest me how can i send the request to the function?

I got following error in firebug.

GET http://localhost/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/controllers/CategoryController/testdata

404 Not Found

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/controllers/CategoryController/Index"

Comment: Don't create json manually...it is error prone. The string you created will not be output as valid json

Comment: If you are new to angular, then why don't you learn it through their [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_01) which will help you understand how requests are made and how responses are handled.

Comment: Also provide a more specific problem statement in your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cust.php you actually need to call the function as well

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   function testdata(){
      $str='{"employees":[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}]}';
      return $str;
  }
  echo testdata();
?>
```

EDIT: I've had to change your $str as well, single quote surrounding keys and values are not valid, I have changed it to double quotes " which are valid.

As @charlietfl has stated it's better practice for you to json_encode your JSON response instead of writing it yourself.

Comment: but i want to pass the function from my angular controller

Comment: What function in your angular controller?

Comment: i want the response of testdata(). 
i will pass this function from my angular controller

Comment: The code I provided returns the response of testdata(). If that's not what you're after, I don't follow.

Comment: won't be valid json in response

Comment: Yes, right. but in cust.php there is more than one function so i wants the response of testdata() only.

Comment: @charlietfl true, I've updated my answer with correct JSON (and you're right, it should be encoded, not hand written). harish, you need to be more clear in your question then.

Comment: @CT14.IT doesn't help just changing quotes in your anwser without explanation also or that change from OP code can easily go undetected

Comment: @charlietfl:- i agree with you. can i pass testdata() function name from   $http.get("../../../frontend/controllers/cust.php")???
so that  i will directly get the response of testdata() function only

Comment: @harish if it is a case of which function then use some sort of GET param like `action` and decide in php controller what to send based on it's value

Comment: Now, i get this error: GET http://localhost/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/controllers/CategoryController/testdata
 
404 Not Found
  angular.min.js (line 86)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/controllers/CategoryController/testdata"

Comment: I update my code here. Please check it and let me know.

Comment: exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Unknown component ID: db' in /var/www/yii2-angular-seed-master/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php:136
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/yii2-angular-seed-master/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(491): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('db')
#1 /var/www/yii2-angular-seed-master/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php(135): yii\base\Application->getDb()
#2 /var/www/yii2-angular-seed-master/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php(305): yii\db\ActiveRecord::getDb()

Answer (score 1):

You can sent your function name in post method and get the method on php page, using that you can perform functions.

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

var request = $http.post('acctUpdate.php', {fun: "testdata"});


        request.success(
        function( html ) {
        console.log(html);
        }
        ); });
```

Comment: Now there is no error. But there is nothing in firebug it shows (an empty string)

Comment: sent response back from the response page.

Comment: how? look here is my funtion:-     function actionIndex(){
  
    $id = 2015;

    return $id;
    }

Comment: is it returning 2015 ?

Comment: in yii we are getting json by       //read the post input (use this technique if you have no post variable name):
  $post = file_get_contents("php://input");

  //decode json post input as php array:
  $data = CJSON::decode($post, true);

Comment: RESPONSE :- <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'yii\web\Controller' not found in <b>/var/www/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/controllers/CategoriesController.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />

Comment: Look my categories controler   <?php
namespace frontend\controllers;
use Yii;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
class CategoriesController extends Controller
{public function actionIndex()
 {
 $post = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
 $data = CJSON::decode($post, true);
 $id = 100;
 return $id;
    }  
}

Comment: do you know actual work flow of yii ? as your code i think you should first go for tutorials, you are hitting the wrong url. 
The URL must be : http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=category
You will get your desired result
I am an expert in YII as well

Comment: first direct hit the yii url through browser and when you get 1000 on screen copy that url and paste it to angular url.

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Controller' not found in <b>/var/www/yii2-angular-seed-master/frontend/controllers/CategoryController.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />